# Shared locks, exclusive locks and data corruption

Tags: php, locking, corrupt

My question is: can **not using** shared locks during *reading* cause *write* errors, even if the write operation **is** using exclusive locks?

Let's say I want to create a file-based counter, like this:

```
//increment counter by 1
$fp = fopen($path, 'r+b');
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {

    //read
    fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    $size = ftell($fp);
    fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if ($size == 0) {
        $counter = 0;
    } else {
        $data = fread($fp, $size);
        $counter = intval($data);
    }

    //do something with data we just read
    $counter ++;

    //write
    fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, $counter);
    fflush($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    fclose($fp);
    throw new Exception("Lock failed");
}
```

Now I want to present it somewhere else:

```
echo intval(file_get_contents($path));
```

Note that `file_get_contents` **does not** use shared locks.

This code has proven to corrupt the data under heavy page load, i.e. counter was reset few times back to 0.

I changed code to use `fopen` and `LOCK_SH` and it seems okay for now, but I have no means to confirm that this indeed was source of the problem as I have no control over load. Local execution of above code using multiple CLI PHP instances suggested that code worked even with `file_get_contents`...

Comment: You have a quite round-about way to read your data within the lock, but nothing in this code should be affected by a parallel read of the file. The non-locked read _might_ see corrupted data (it might catch the instant between `ftruncate` and `fwrite`, so it might see empty file), but it should not affect the data read inside the lock. You also don't need to explicitly unlock your file before closing — closing implicitly releases all locks, as it is not possible to hold a lock on a closed file.

Comment: Your code can leave a dangling file pointer.  You throw the exception if you can't get the lock, but the file is already open at that point.  You should close it before throwing the exception.

Comment: Thanks, updated the post. Although pointers are closed automatically when script finishes, it is certainly better to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...finally, found the culprit. Our production server has `flock` function turned off and unfortunately we are in no position to change that. I guess I'll have to implement custom locking mechanism.

This is due to production server having NFS file system and locking files on NFS not working at all in most cases.

Comment: You don't have control over your own production server?

Comment: @Jack: Having control over it, and being in a position to alter its configuration, are two _very_ different things. It's a _production server_.

Comment: @Light sure, but it seemed like it was just disabled in php.ini

Comment: @Jack Yeah and on a _production server_ you don't just go tinkering around in `php.ini`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course, but that's also why you have staging servers :)

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the manual for [ftell](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) discuss unpredictable behavior for files opened with append mode. Maybe you could try to open the file in read only for the read, or just read the file anyway, I don't see why you have a line in the code that can explicity set the counter to 0.

```
echo intval(false); //0
```

And fread at EOF returns false, so:

```
$fp = fopen($path, 'r+b');
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {

    //read
    $data = fread($fp, $size);
    $counter = intval($data);

    //do something with data we just read
    $counter ++;

    //write
    fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ftruncate($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, $counter);
    fflush($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    fclose($fp);
    throw new Exception("Lock failed");
}
```

Comment: The file is opened with `r+b` mode and I'm doing `ftell` since results from `filesize` are based on _cached_ result of internal `stat`. Calling `clearstatcache` doesn't look very nice to me.

Comment: Then again, `fread` accepts two parameters - you _must_ specify how much you want to read.